Smartd reporting vastly different information than the Disks app in Ubuntu
I turned on the smartd scan of my drives to get an email if any errors appear in my RAID 1 setup, and I started getting alarming emails from every drive. A typical daily email for each drive looks like this:
Device: /dev/sdd [SAT], 203270600 Offline uncorrectable sectors (changed +19676)

But when I look at the drives in the Ubuntu Disks app and it's SMART Data & self tests, I get a clean bill of health for each drive, no reallocated or uncorrectable sectors and overall assessment of "Disk is OK".
This is what I put in my /etc/smartd.conf for each drive:
/dev/sde -H -C 0 -U 0 -m my@email.com -s (S/../.././02)

I'm at a loss, and hoping I'm not about to have a failure on every drive. Hopefully it's just user error on my part with the config.
All of these drives are in a RAID controller, so perhaps that is causing some issue with smartd accessing the drives directly.
